# Body goes off-canvas

Tags: html, css, layout

I try to fix the layout, because if you see this link from you mobile you can see that the whole right part goes off canvas for some pixels.

I tried setting a `max-width:1280px;` attribute but it didnt work. Does anyone an easy fix?
Maybe I should define a body max-width ?

http://www.2kfilms.com/films.html

Comment: This question does not show any research effort and it is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In your `page` and `films-list` styles you are defining fixed with. These will never be 'squeezed'. If you want them to get smaller somahow you need to define them differently. There may be more places in your code where you are doing that. Fix that to fit.